# Coredata Remove and Read Relationship

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

Is it possible to remove and read a relationship?

I cannot post the code here since it is a huge project with very complex process.

Let's say I have tableA <-->> tableB
tableB gets updated (i.e., tableB objects will be deleted and new obejcts (re)added). I check if objects from tableA had a relationship with tableB, which I already have in an array with server object id. I now read the data in tableB and readd the relationship. The relationship gets faulted and cannot be accessed. After I add or remove an object I save it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The relationship is faulted because you removed the objects. If you want the relationship to be present in your new tableB objects you must transfer the relationship before you delete the objects. (Save the pointer to tableA and reassign it to the new objects in tableB)

Comment: how to save the relationship? i mean the relationship has pointer to old object. shouldnt one readd relationship?

Comment: But you removed all the objects to tableB, right? Then all of the relationships that were attached to the objects in tableB would be nullified (if that is your deletion rule). What is the name of tableA's class?

Comment: yeah exactly it gets nullified.tableA and tableB are the classes name. and they are different classes (entities). is that what you want to know?

Comment: Yeah that's what I was wondering. What are the relationships called on `tableA -->> tableB` and `tableB --> tableA`?

Comment: yeah exactly that's the relationship type tableA<-->> tableB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was caused when object inserted into tableA. the relationship objects come from different contexts. although i had merge policy `NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy` still the object had unresolvable faults. i changed the code so that both object were in same context. and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I am misunderstanding your intentions here but I will give it a try and modify as needed. First, all entities should start with a capital letter, so I will be using `TableA` and `TableB` for my entities. Also `TableA` and `TableB` are terrible names for coredata entities. They are atrociously generic and if you ever decide to use them outside of your tables it could really confuse your code. Especially since it is a "huge project with very complex process."

This is in essence what I believe you are seeking:

```
// defined elsewhere
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

// saving the the object that you want to connect to later
TableA *relationshipToA = self.AllTableBs.tableARelationship;

// remove all TableB objects from coredata as you are already doing
// ...
// // //

// insert new TableB objects setting their tableARelationship to relationshipToA
// ...
// //

// single example
TableB *bObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TableB" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
bObject.tableARelationship = relationshipToA;

// save context
```

Then when you attempt to access your objects relationship to TableA it is valid and vice versa.

Comment: thanks for the effort. i 'll try it later and report. ( tableA and tableB were just for the sake of example ;-))

Comment: ok i have found out a mistake in relationship. so its tableA<--> tableB. but still nor with your suggestion nor witj my way it works. one more thing the tableA was added with other nsmanagedcontext and tableB withB and new relationship with other context. could it be the cuase of never resolveable fault?

Comment: Yeah that could be the problem, depending. Each `NSManagedObjectContext` has a persistent store. So the if you added `TableA` with `contextA` and later added the relationship with `contextB` then only `contextB` would have that relationship because `contextA` would have an outdated persistent store. Try re-alloc and `init`ing `contextA`.

Comment: I have retest that. TableA adds a record with relationship to tableB. It works even TableA and B were from different context. But when adding TableA tableB record is in same context. But when only updating tableB and relinking to TableA doesn't work